# VueJS 3 $delete component

Tags: migration, vuejs3

How can I make a component delete itself in Vue 3?

In Vue 2 you could say `this.$destroy();` But apparently that got removed and there is no replacement for it: "vm.$delete removed (no longer needed)" (from https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html#fully-compatible )

Not sure why it's no longer needed since they don't explain why or give an alternative and I can definitely still see the need for something like this.

For now I just use a `<div v-if="show">` but it seems a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

From Vue 3 docs you can find it here: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#removed-apis that you don't need to manually manage the component lifecycle anymore. So I guess you can deprecate the piece of code executing ".$destroy()".

Comment: But how do I tell Vue then that this component is not there anymore?

When I have a component created from an object in an array I can see this work if you remove the object from the array but if it's just a single component is the `v-if="false"` on the root element of this component enough to completely destroy it?

Comment: It should, or even if it doesn't, Vue should be the one handling if it needs to "destroy"(now called unmount) the component. You can test this by adding an unmounted handler and see for yourself that the component is behaving as you expect.

Comment: Putting the v-if in the parent on the component itself does indeed trigger the `unmounted`. That makes sense but it still is a miss that this can't be done from within the component.
I'll try to create some construction that a component will check it's parent for itself and remove it that way somehow (so without the need for code in the parent).
But the documentation saying `this.$delete()` is not needed anymore and not giving a decent alternative is quite a bummer.

Comment: You should think that not needing to use `this.$delete()` is actually a friendlier and safer approach, maybe even more performant. The component will be unmounted when is not needed anymore, automatically. I guess that to have a manual approach would need a strong reason for it that might not be so necessary in Vue 3 than it was in Vue 2.

Comment: Still what would you suggest with for example a "message box" component with it's own close button? How would I remove/delete/unmount/whatever it without "bothering" it's parent. I would assume there is a way for the child itself to say "I'm not needed anymore"

Comment: It depends, I can't assume about your situation. My guess would be that the child should not decide when it's not needed. That's the parent's job. Is not that the child is bothering the parent. If you create the child,  either a direct one or not, it will always have a link open between this "message box"(child in this scenario) and something else, a parent is one possibility, vuex store is another. This is what holds the existence of that message box. The "close" button is only informing the intention of not wanting to exist anymore, in that way letting A parent know when to "destroy" them.